# Given $\{A_n\}$, with $P\left(A_n\right)\to 1$, there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k\ge 1} \;$ such that $\; P\left(\bigcap_k A_{n_k}\right) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

This is problem 4.21a is Resnick's *Probability Path*.

> Suppose $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of events. If $P(A_n)\to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, prove that there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ tending to infinity such that $P(\bigcap_k A_{n_k})>0$. (Hint: Use Borel-Cantelli.)

Having searched a bit on here for related problems, I've gotten the impression that what most people mean by Borel-Cantelli is something a little more expansive than what Resnick means, which is that for some sequence of (not necessarily independent) events $\{A_n\}$, if $\sum P(A_n) < \infty$, then $P(\limsup_n A_n) = 0$. Since the $\{A_n\}$ in question are not independent, I can't use any results on sequences whose sums don't converge.

Clearly, $P(A_n)\to 1$ implies that $\sum P(A_n) = \infty$, and so I can't directly apply Borel-Cantelli. Moreover, even though $P(A_n^c)\to 0$, this does not imply that $\sum P(A_n^c)<\infty$, so I can't do anything with the complements. I'm not sure what else to do:  I mean, if I could somehow determine that $P(\limsup_n A_n) = 1$, I could show that $\sum P(A_n) = \infty$ ... but then I could just reread the first sentence of this paragraph.

Could anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no need to use Borel-Cantelli here. Observe that $$P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n_k}\right) > 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n_k}^{c}\right) < 1$$
Now because $P(A_{n}^{c}) \to 0$, we can choose a subsequence $n_{k}$ such that $$P(A_{n_k}^{c}) < 3^{-(k+1)}$$

Comment: Nice! Thank you! By the way, do you think that Borel-Cantelli is simply unnecessary? Or is it just irrelevant?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the question or not, I wouldn't say that the Lemma of Borel-Cantelli is useless, but definitely not required to prove this statement and thus I'd say irrelevant in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Take any $A_i$ s.t. $P(A_i)=a>0$. Take any series of positive numbers $b_i$ s.t. $\sum_1^{\infty} b_i=b<a$. Let $n_0=i$ and for each $i\geq 1$ pick $n_i>n_{i-1}$ s.t. $P(A^c_{n_i})<1-b_i$. Then $P(\bigcap_k A_{n_k})> a-b>0$

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna have to ruminate on this a bit :). One question, though: Can we assume that such an $A_i$ exists? Or are we really saying something like "Pick $A_i$ such that $i$ is the smallest index such that the event has probability at least $a$"?

Comment: I meant to say that you pick any $A_i$ with $P(A_i)>0$ and call that probability $a$.